# Using taskset to set processor affinity

Tags: linux, cpu, scheduling, taskset

I have the following code in a bash script:

```
echo "bash pid => $$";
echo "processor affinity before => $(taskset -p $$)"
taskset -cp ${AN_INTEGER} $$
echo "processor affinity after => $(taskset -p $$)"
```

I get this output:

```
processor affinity before => pid 5047's current affinity mask: ff
pid 5047's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 5047's new affinity list: 1
processor affinity after => pid 5047's current affinity mask: 2
```

does anyone know what this means?

The reason I started messing with processor affinity is because I would launch multiple bash child processes, and all the bash child process affinities had the value "ff" so it seemed like they were all targeting the same CPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`taskset`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/taskset.1.html) uses a mask to specify which CPUs a process can run on. Each bit maps to one CPU; if a bit is set to 1, the process can run on that CPU, if it’s set to 0, it can’t. Thus a mask of FF means any CPU from 0 to 7 (not one specific CPU), and a mask of 2 means only CPU 1.